# Usage of tf.gather_nd

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose that you have a 3-tensor

```
data = np.reshape(np.arange(12), [2, 2, 3])
x = tf.constant(data)
```

Thinking of this as 2x2 matrices indexed by the last index, I would like to get the first column from the first matrix, the second column from the second matrix and the second column from the third matrix.

How can I use tf.gather_nd to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need first generate the indices you want.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

indices = [[i,min(j,1),j] for j in range(3) for i in range(2)]  # According to your description
# [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]

a = tf.constant(np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3))

res = tf.gather_nd(a, indices)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a.eval()
# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [ 3,  4,  5]],

#        [[ 6,  7,  8],
#         [ 9, 10, 11]]])

res.eval()
# array([ 0,  6,  4, 10,  5, 11])
```

Comment: Thank you, and what if that third index was unknown? Essentially, the third dimension is the batch size and I want to select elements from those 2x2 tensors based on each sample's properties.

Comment: I see, you can try `indices=[[i,sel_col[j],j] for j in range(B) for i in range(2)]`. `B` is the batch_size, and `sel_col` is a dict that indicates which col should be selected from 2x2 matrix for j-th samples.

Comment: But the batch size is unknown in general. I posted a streamlined solution in a separate answer which works given the batch size, but what is it is None?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following tutorial online explaining how to deal with this kind of problems: https://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com/2018/05/fancy-indexing-in-tensorflow-getting.html

Suppose we have a 4x3 matrix

```
M = tf.constant(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))
```

Now let's say that you wanted the third element of the first row, the second element of the second row, the first element of the third row, and the second element of the fourth row. As explained in the tutorial, this could be accomplished like:

```
idx = tf.constant([2,1,0,1], tf.int32)
x = tf.gather_nd(M, tf.stack([tf.range(M.shape[0]), idx], axis=1))
```

But **what if M has an unknown number of rows? (and idx as a tensor of integers of the appropriate size)** Then tf.range(M.shape[0]) will raise an error. How can I go around that?